# За (городом) Королёвом/Королёвым?

Tags: грамматика

"За Королёвом" или "за Королёвым", если имеется в виду город в Московской области?
Чем руководствоваться и почему?
Спасибо.

~~~~
22.10
Вопрос в том, чем вызван такой подход... Вопрос "почему так" в данном случае вполне уместен, ведь речь идет не о традиции и не о соображениях грамматике, ибо подобное - явно чье-то субъективное решение. 
При этом топонимы типа "Горький" почему-то не подвергаются подобным изменениям. Под городом Горьким, где ясные зорьки"... По аналогии топоним должен бы полностью субстантивироваться: "Под Городом Горькием". Как под кием, палладием, кием, Афанасием.

Comment: А  почему  в  одном  случае  Ё,  а  в  другом  Е ?

Comment: Здесь, видимо, у автора просто опечатка.

Comment: Да, нужно ё в обоих случаях.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Фамилии на -ИН/-ЫН и -ЕВ/-ОВ по своему происхождению --- краткие притяжательные имена прилагательные:
Василий ---> сын (чей?) ВАСИЛЬЕВ. ПЁТР ---> сын (чей?) ПЕТРОВ и под. Притяжательные имена прилагательные в истории русского языка стали разрушаться (причины опускаю) (ср. высказывание известного лингвиста А.А.Шахматова: "Судьба притяжательных имен прилагательных лишена перспектив.." -- Синтаксис русского языка. -- Л., 1927. -- С.82), и это, в частности, проявлялось в том, что их падежная парадигма становилась смешанной: в некоторых формах сохранялись старые формы (кратких прилагательных), а в других с 19 в. появлялись новые (полных имен прилагательных). И в современном русском языке падежная парадигма кратких притяжательных имен прилагательных выглядит так:

И.ед.= В.ед. отц-ов-0 (краткие формы)

Р.ед. отц-ов-А // отц-ов-ОГО (и краткая, и полная формы, чаще --- полная)

Д.ед. отц-ов-у / отц-ов-ОМУ (и краткая, и полная формы, чаще --- полная)

Т.ед. ОТЦ-ОВ-ЫМ (полная форма вытеснила краткую)

П.ед. отц-ов-ОМ (полная йорма вытеснила краткую).

Притяжательные имена прилагательные-фамилии стали передаваться, в силу установившейся культурной традиции,  от отца к сыну, от сына к отцу и т.д. и перестали восприниматься как притяжательные имена прилагательные, они теперь имена существительные
ТВОРИТЕЛЬНЫЙ падеж у этих образований -- фамилий (см. вопрос) СОХРАНЯЕТСЯ, однако, С ОКОНЧАНИЕМ ПОЛНОГО ИМЕНИ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОГО: познакомиться с КОРОЛЁВ-ЫМ.

Так получилось, что ряд русских поселений (городов, сёл и т.п.)стали называть в честь каких-либо известных писателей, политических деятелей, ученых и т.п.: город ПУШКИН, село БОРОДИНО, город КОРОЛЁВ и под. Грамматически это --- имена существительные (названия предметов), и,естественно, они склоняются по типу ИМЕН СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫХ:

И.п. город-0 КОРОЛЁВ-0

Р.п. город-а КОРОЛЁВ-А

Д.п. город-У КОРОЛЁВ-У

В.п.=И.п.

Т.п ГОРОД-ОМ КОРОЛЁВ-ОМ (исторически < -ЪМЬ)

П.п. о город-е КОРОЛЁВ-Е

Так, по моему мнению. и появилось различие в окончаниях Творительного падежа  ИС-фамилий (бывших притяжательных имен прилагательных) и ИС-топонимов: 
Т.п. встретиться с ученым Королёв-ЫМ, но: самолет летит над городом Королёв-ОМ. Это различие в использовании окончаний закрепилось в соответствующем орфографическом правиле.

Comment: Спасибо. Да, все это так, одни склоняются по парадигме существительного, другие  - прилагательного. Это понятно. Но вопрос в общем-то был в том, как случилось, что закрепилось именно такое различие. Обе формы восходят к притяжательному прилагательному, никаких видимых отличий нет...  
Ну да ладно, актуальность пропала.  
Жаль, что Шахматов не пояснил, какие случаи куда относить. Может, дело просто во времени появления этих форм?

Answer (score 7):

За Королев**ом**.

> Географические названия на -ов (-ев),
>   -ово (-ево), -ин, -ино (-ыно) имеют в творительном падеже окончание -ом,
>   например: Львов – Львовом, Канев –
>   Каневом, Крюково – Крюковом, Камышин –
>   Камышином, Марьино – Марьином,
>   Голицыно – Голицыном.
>
> В отличие от
>   названий городов русские фамилии на
>   -ин (-ын) и на -ов (-ев) имеют в творительном падеже единственного
>   числа окончание -ым, ср.: Пушкин
>   (фамилия) – Пушкиным и Пушкин (город)
>   – Пушкином; Александров (фамилия) –
>   Александровым и Александров (город) –
>   Александровом.

[ПИСЬМОВНИК | gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_90)

Comment: Ну да согласен, что там -ом, но почему?  Другими словами, почему такое правило что в "отличие от". Я путаюсь свести к каким-то понятным материям... За "Пушкиным городом"? Не продходит...

Comment: Думаю, чтобы не замедлять чтение(при оформлении издания это — одно из главных условий, по той же причине необходимо единообразие при сокращении-несокращении, например, единиц измерения), чтобы одно имя собственное не путалось с другим, совершенно не связанным с ним по смыслу, но идентичным по написанию.

Comment: Нет, смыслоразличительная функция орфографии в данном случае никак не может быть привлечена, поскольку речь идет о различиях не орфографических, а о грамматике и фонетике.

Я дополнил вопрос.

Answer (score 7):

Виной всему морфологический (или морфемный) принцип русской орфографии: необходимо сохранять единообразное написание всех значащих частей слова (морфем, то есть приставок, корней, суффиксов и окончаний), несмотря на различие в их произношении.
Фамилия Пушкин-существительное,образованное от клички прадеда Пушка. Склоняется так же, как притяжательные прилагательные.Корень(по Зализняку): -Пуш-; суффиксы: -к-ин-.Поэтому Тв.пад.-кем?(как в прилагат. чьим?)- Пушкиным.
Топоним Пушкин -существительное с корнем -Пушкин-, 2-е склонение. Вот и склоняется по 2 склонению Чем?- столом, Пушкином.
Иностранные фамилии тоже нечленимы в русском языке, если оканчиваются на согласный, тоже склоняются по 2 склонению.

Comment: А можно поконретней, а то опять "многабукафф".

Как все эти красивые слова о единообразии соотносятся с тем, что андроним (фамилия) и топоним склоняются по разным правилам?

А порассуждать о типах склонения, притяжательных суффиксах и падежных вопросах - это я и сам умею.

Comment: Чего уж тут не понимать:фамилия склоняется так же, как прилагательное, географическое название - как  сущ. 2 склонения, потому что Пушкин - всё слово - корень(как стол -столом).

Comment: Ну, ответ типа "Что тут понимать?" достаточно универсален, но понимания не добавляет.  
Я не хочу запоминать, я хочу понять, чем это объясняется. А ответа нет.

Comment: Чтобы понять, нужно разобраться в морфологическом принципе, а это снова "многабукафф": фамилия - Пушкин сын - притяж. прил., членима, суфф. -ин-с кем? с Пушк/ин/ым сыном(оконч. прил. тв. п.); топоним нечленим, корень -Пушкин- встретились где? - под Пушкин/ом (оконч. сущ 2 скл в тв. пад)

Comment: Вот это как раз не "многабукафф", а скорее "мало", ибо объяснение в подобных терминах вплоне допустимо.  
  
Но тут-то отсылка к нечленимости ничего не объясняет. Почему топоним нечленим - и чем он по сути отличается от андронима? И когда он, топоним, стал таковым? Аналогия то полная. Чей сын - чей город.
 
Еще в пошлом веке топонимы были вполне себе не только членимы, но и образовывали особые формы склонения типа "Вышел из Новагорода" (см. Карамзина, например), "села (и города) Царицына" и даже "Киев**ым** градом".

Царицын, кстаи, прекрасный пример. Как его склонять?

Comment: У Виноградова:
http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5310&0a0=8 Назв.городов на-ов субстантивировались давно, на -ин позже . В  18 и 1 четв.19 в.они пишутся,как и фамилии.Потом семантика чей сын? осталась в фамилиях, а вот притяжательность городов исчезла. Чей город? сказать нельзя, скорее в честь кого?( относительн.прил.). Но в некот.(Царицын)оставалась притяж., пошла путаница. В совр.языке,отчасти под влиянием живого произношения,(-ом и -ым)совпадают, отчасти от желания  избежать омонимии ,закрепилось в тв.п.-ом за всеми назв. городов с суффиксами -ов, -ин, -ово,.-ино (если склоняются).

Answer (score 2):

Просто запомнить, что названия населенных пунктов на -ов, -ев, -ин, -ын, -ово, -ево, -ино, -ыно имеют в творительном падеже окончание -ом. Например: за Царицыном, под Киевом, за Королёвом.

И дополнение: в отличие от названия городов,  русские фамилии на -ов(ёв), -ев, -ин, -ын имеют в творительном падеже единственного числа окончание -ым. Например: За КоролёвЫМ стояла его жена. Но: За КоролёвОМ (городом) находится аэродром.

Comment: Да, спасибо, мне уже давно дали ссылку на источник (да я его и сам знал).
Вопрос в том, чем вызван такой подход... Вопрос "почему так" в данном случае вполне уместен, ведь речь идет не о традиции и не о соображениях грамматике, ибо подобное - явно чье-то субъективное решение. 
При этом топонимы типа "Горький" почему-то не подввргаеются подоным изменениям. Под городом Горьким, где ясные зорьки"... По аналогии топоним должен бы полностью субстантивироваться: "Под Городом Горькием". Как под кием, палладием, кием, Афанасием.